# Select some image tags using regex

Tags: php, html, regex, image

I have this code that selects all `<img>` tags:

```
$pattern = "@<img[^>]*src=[\"\']([^\"\']*)[\"\'][^>]*>@";
```

I want to change it that only selects images that do not have "noajax" in its class. for example:

`<img src="../" />` -> should be selected

`<img src="../" class="noresize noajax" />` -> should NOT be selected

Comment: I'll add the standard comment that RegEx is the wrong tool to use to parse HTML. If your case is narrow and you're not dealing with arbitrary HTML, it might be 'good enough', but in the real world it will keep biting you.

Comment: @RikHeywood: forget it. All is lost. He comes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img[^>]*src=[\"\']([^\"\']*)[\"\'](?:(?!\bnoajax\b|>).)*>
```

Try this.This should work for you case.

Comment: I want to change it that only sellects all images that have not "noajax" in its class

Answer (score 0):

@RikHeywood's comment is correct.  I would recommend XPath as the preferred tool to solve this problem.

```
//img[not(contains(@class, 'noajax'))]
```

This should select every  in your document that does not have any class with the text "noajax".

A quick bit of googling suggests this as a place to start for how to evaluate XPaths in PHP.
http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php

Edit: forgot link.